# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'quantity' property

Tags: php, soap

My problem is this error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'quantity' property

Code that executes it is:

```
while($Data = pg_fetch_row($GetData)){
    $ID = $Data[0]; $ID_C = $Data[1]; $UserLogin = $Data[2];
    $Barcode = $Data[3]; $Quantity = $Data[4]; $ADate = $Data[5];
    $Date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ADate));
    $Datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($ADate));

    try{
      $SOAP = new SoapClient($TrawersAddress);
      $Response = $SOAP->InventoryReceipt(array('item' =>
          array('idx' => "$IDX"),
          array('ean' => "$Barcode"),
          array('workOrderPrefix' => "LS0001"),
          array('workOrderSuffix' => "000"),
          array('quantity' => "$Quantity")
        ),
        array('adeptKey' => "XXXX1"),
        array('creationDate' => "$Date"),
        array('to' => "0"),
        array('note' => "Wykonał: $UserLogin - $Datetime"),
        array('documentType' => "PR")
      );
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
      echo $e -> getMessage();
    }
    $IDX++;
  }
```

When I delete this piece of code

```
array('quantity' => "$Quantity")
```

Error stays the same. I tried a lot of other combinations but error is still the same (about quantity). I did something wrong with this code or just wrong use api?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem just by using a huuge string variable with all XML body in it and then sending it by cURL. After contact with developer of application I wanted to connect to, he told me that WSDL connection in his app is don't working properly.